# Issues with using Scoverage: Scala Sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, test-coverage, scoverage

I added the scoverage plugin to projects/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.3.5")
```

I was able to generate test coverage using

```
sbt clean coverage test
sbt coveragereport
```

However when I try to add socverage config to my build.sbt. I see build errors

```
error: value ScoverageKeys is not a member of object scoverage.ScoverageSbtPlugin
ScoverageSbtPlugin.ScoverageKeys.coverageMinimum := 70
```

Looks like build.sbt does not find Scoverage classes. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [that](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/blob/v1.3.5/src/main/scala/scoverage/ScoverageKeys.scala) out. Seems like what you need is:

```
scoverage.ScoverageKeys.coverageMinimum := 70
```